# Finite string fixed at one end and connected to frictional massless bead

Tags: waves, string, boundary-conditions, normal-modes

Assume we have a finite string of length $L$. The string has tension $T$ and wave speed $c$.
The string is fixed at $x=0$ and connected to a massless bead at $x=L$ that can slide on a rod. The rod applies friction on the bead of the form $F_{fric} = -Cv$, where $v$ is the velocity of the bead. What are the eigenmodes of the string?

I start by writing the general form of the eigenmodes. Since the string is fixed at $x=0$, they take the form
$$
\psi(x,t)=\sin{kx}\left(A\cos\omega t+B\sin\omega t\right)
$$

The boundary condition at the right end is that the sum of forces equal zero, since the bead is massless, which results in
$$
-T\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}-C\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=0
$$
Applying this boundary condition, we get
$$
-Tk\cos{kL}\left(A\cos\omega t+B\sin\omega t\right)=\omega C\sin{kL}\left(-A\sin{\omega t}+B\cos\omega t\right)
$$
Equating coefficient of the temporal functions, and using $\omega =ck$ we get two contradictory equations
$$
-TA\cos{kL}=cCB\sin{kL}
$$

$$
TB\cos{kL}=cCA\sin{kL}
$$

These equations happen simultaneously only when $A=B=0$, which means there is no non-trivial solution.

Where am I wrong?